# Django Index Error: List Index out of Range using try catch

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

How do I throw in a try catch exception if there is no data within field issuedbook? I haven't put any data inside issuedbook for debugging purposes and I just want it to say "No Data found" or "You have no books issued"

Here is my views.py:

```python
def viewissuedbookbystudent(request):
        student=models.StudentExtra.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        issuedbook=models.IssuedBook.objects.filter(enrollment=student[0].enrollment)

        li1=[]
        li2=[]

        for ib in issuedbook:
            books=models.Book.objects.filter(isbn=ib.isbn)
            for book in books:
                t=(request.user,student[0].enrollment,student[0].branch,book.name,book.author)
                li1.append(t)
            issdate=str(ib.issuedate.day)+'-'+str(ib.issuedate.month)+'-'+str(ib.issuedate.year)
            expdate=str(ib.expirydate.day)+'-'+str(ib.expirydate.month)+'-'+str(ib.expirydate.year)
            #fine calculation
            days=(date.today()-ib.issuedate)
            print(date.today())
            d=days.days
            fine=0
            if d>15:
                day=d-15
                fine=day*10
            t=(issdate,expdate,fine)
            li2.append(t)
        context={'li1':li1,'li2':li2}
        return render(request,'library/viewissuedbookbystudent.html',context)
```

I get this error every time I run it and I know it's because of no data within issuedbook field:

```
IndexError at /viewissuedbookbystudent

list index out of range

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/viewissuedbookbystudent
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     IndexError
Exception Value:    

list index out of range

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 318, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.4
Python Path:    

['E:\\C drive\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\librarymanagement-master',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages'
```

Here is my template for this, if it helps:

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-right:0px;">
    {% if li1%}
    <table class="redTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Enrollment</th>
  <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Book Title</th>
      <th>Book Author</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">
  <div class="links"></div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    {% for t in li1 %}
<tr>
  <td>  {{t.0}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.1}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.2}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.3}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.4}}</td>
</tr>

    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-left:0px;">

      <table class="redTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Issue Date</th>
    <th>Expiry Date</th>
    <th>Fine</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <div class="links"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      {% for t in li2 %}
<tr>
  <td>  {{t.0}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.1}}</td>
  <td>  {{t.2}}</td>
</tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    {%else%}
    <h1> No book Issued to you</h1>
    {%endif%}

</div>

</div>
```

This is the models.py:

```
class StudentExtra(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enrollment = models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name=_('Student ID'))
    course = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    #used in issue book
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.last_name+'['+str(self.enrollment)+']'
    @property
    def get_name(self):
        return self.user.last_name
    @property
    def getuserid(self):
        return self.user.id

class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')
        ordering = ['id']

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Category'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Book')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Books')
        ordering = ['id']

    title=models.CharField(max_length=130)
    isbn=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)+"["+str(self.isbn)+']'


def get_expiry():
    return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=15)

class IssuedBook(models.Model):
    #moved this in forms.py
    #enrollment=[(student.enrollment,str(student.get_name)+' ['+str(student.enrollment)+']') for student in StudentExtra.objects.all()]
    enrollment=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    #isbn=[(str(book.isbn),book.name+' ['+str(book.isbn)+']') for book in Book.objects.all()]
    isbn=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    issuedate=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    expirydate=models.DateField(default=get_expiry)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.enrollment
```

I have Traceback as well:
[Traceback.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrxgg.png)

Can I fix it using a try catch? If yes, how?

Comment: Not directly related to the error, but why are you using `.filter()` instead of `.get()`?  User ID's and ISBNs are unique, right?  You wouldn't ever get more than one record for those filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use messages in the following manner

**View Part**

```py
from django.contrib import messages
def viewissuedbookbystudent(request):
        student=models.StudentExtra.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        issuedbook=models.IssuedBook.objects.filter(enrollment=student[0].enrollment)

        li1=[]
        li2=[]
        try:
            for ib in issuedbook:
                books=models.Book.objects.filter(isbn=ib.isbn)
                for book in books:
                    t=(request.user,student[0].enrollment,student[0].branch,book.name,book.author)
                    li1.append(t)
                issdate=str(ib.issuedate.day)+'-'+str(ib.issuedate.month)+'-'+str(ib.issuedate.year)
                expdate=str(ib.expirydate.day)+'-'+str(ib.expirydate.month)+'-'+str(ib.expirydate.year)
                #fine calculation
                days=(date.today()-ib.issuedate)
                print(date.today())
                d=days.days
                fine=0
                if d>15:
                    day=d-15
                    fine=day*10
                t=(issdate,expdate,fine)
                li2.append(t)
            context={'li1':li1,'li2':li2}
            return render(request,'library/viewissuedbookbystudent.html',context)
        except IndexError as e:
            messages.info(request, 'You have no books issued')
```

**Template part**

```html
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry still getting same error, and no messages comes out

Comment: Then try moving the `try:` line to just below `def viewissuedbookbystudent(request):`

Comment: just used this in the last part and it worked:
    except IndexError as e:
        return render(request, 'library/viewissuedbookbystudent.html',{'e':e})

Answer (score 1):

If you want an Exception to raise and bubble up to the caller, do something like this:

```py
try:
    this_student = student[0]
except IndexError:
    # Raise whatever exception you want here:
    raise ValueError(f"No student found when processing {whatever}") from None

# now use this_student where you used student[0]
```

If you want to "handle" the IndexError, do whatever error handling/logging you need for "it to say" what you want within that except block.

Alternatively, you could check `if len(student) > 0:` and avoid try-blocks altogether.

Comment: sorry it's not student, just edited recently it's issuedbook but i tried this_issuedbook=issuedbook[0] and still same error

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
issuedbook = None
student=StudentExtra.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
try:
   issuedbook=IssuedBook.objects.filter(enrollment=student[0].enrollment)
except IndexError:
   print("No books have been issued yet")
```

Do make sure you declare issuedbook as None if you are using it later in views. You can also store a string in the except block in any variable and return it wherever you want. You still need to declare the variable as None beforehand.